# Refresh particular folder Through c# or registry operations

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

I have implemented icon overlay, and are updating fine, but only issue that i'm facing is i need to refresh the folder to get the new overlay. Let me know if there any way to refresh particular folder from c# code or through some registry operations.

I have added my short cut to the left pane of the file explorer. I need to refresh that as well. Currently I'm refreshing the explorer itself to get the new overlay but it works like a noise since it refreshes all opened windows and also the icons in the task bar.

Hope that someone will suggest some options for me.

Comment: When you say refresh, do you mean right click->refresh and/or F5, or something else entirely?  This seems more like a programming question though.

Comment: Yes, similar to `right click->refresh and/or F5`

Comment: similar or exactly?  If its exactly, just have a routine, that sends the sends the F5 key.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: That would be a programming question.

Comment: Look into setting some sendkey function that if the new version date the exe is clicked then press F5 or something. If you promoted a new file icon, etc. and the exe has change versions, etc. related to changes you make, just say if the current date and some reversion date is the same, then press F5 when the exe is used. If it's been longer than that same day, I would say it's safe to assume the client has logged off or back on, or went out the folder in Windows explorer and back into it by then... at least you'd think this perhaps. Just a quick idea without a lot more detail from you.